# Spring Security form login using database

Tags: database, spring, logging, authentication, spring-security

I use spring security using database for logging in. I can see the login page, but the page just repeats when I try to log in even there is no error message. I do not know whether it works, because it returns to the loggin page. 
here is my code.

security xml

```
<http auto-config="true">
   <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
   <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login" default-target-url="/admin"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider>
   <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
        users-by-username-query="SELECT USERID, PASSWORD FROM USERINFO WHERE V_USERID=?" 
        authorities-by-username-query="SELECT USERID, USERNAME FROM USERINFO WHERE USERID = ? AND PASSWORD=?"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

login jsp

```
<form method="POST" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />">
   <table class="login">
   <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="j_username"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>PASSWORD</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="j_password"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="confirm">
       <input type="reset" value="reset"></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

controller java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model mode){
   return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(
   @RequestParam(value="list", required=false) String list, Model model) {
   return "home";
}
```

Comment: I think because you are returning "login" from @RequestMapping(value = "/login"), you are getting redirected to login page again without error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `authentication-failure-url="/login"` to `authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1"` That way you can check the url for `error=1` or even better you can check it in the jsp and show error message.